# How Can I add Text to a RichTextBlock from the code behind in a c++ winrt UWP app,

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, c++-winrt

Given xaml code like

```xml
<RichTextBlock x:Name="richb"> </RichTextBlock>
```

How can I add text to the RichTextBlock named richb from the c++ code behind?

If it were a TextBlock it would just be

```cpp
richb().Text(L"Any text can go here");
```

However this does not work for a RichTextBlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichTextBlock is different from TextBlock, you need to use Paragraph elements to define the blocks of text to display within a RichTextBlock control. About more information, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock).

```
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Documents;


Paragraph paragraph = Paragraph();
Run run = Run();

// Customize some properties on the RichTextBlock.
richb().IsTextSelectionEnabled(true);
richb().TextWrapping(TextWrapping::Wrap);
run.Text(L"This is some sample text to show the wrapping behavior.");

// Add the Run to the Paragraph, the Paragraph to the RichTextBlock.
paragraph.Inlines().Append(run);
richb().Blocks().Append(paragraph);
```

Comment: The ``` #include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents.h>``` Part was especially helpful. Thank you.